# List of all available UIActivityType for sharing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I need to customize the share window while sharing media. Is there an API to fetch a list of all the available activities on iOS? There is a way to exclude certain activities, but what about just fetching a list of all the activities that I can share to?